# crystal reports conditional formatting for summary fields

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a decimal formatting formula on my summary fields. The values in the database could have 0, 1, or 2 decimal places. I've started with this:

```
If (CurrentFieldValue mod 1 = 0) Then
            0
Else If (CurrentFieldValue mod .1 = 0) Then
            1
Else
            2
```

On a simple single data field, this works and displays the value with 0, 1, or 2 decimal places based on the data coming from my database. The same formula doesn't work for a summary field on my reports with group data. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Since I don't know how to format code in a comment, I'll address the suggestion of using a formula here:

Didn't work. Formula:

```
Sum ({myTable.dataValue}, {myTable.groupField})
```

then I used:

```
If ({@formula} mod 1 = 0) Then
    0
Else If ({@formula} mod .1 = 0) Then
    1
Else
    2
```

And I still got whole numbers for everything. My rounding is set to .01 with no formula. Do I need a formula for rounding too? I still don't understand why this works on individual values but not for group summaries.

Comment: try adding `whileprintingrecords;` before your code quoted above

Comment: @LeeTickett no dice, I still get all whole number values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK- it turns out this is due to our lack of understanding of the mod function :)

Everything mod 1 actually returns 0. This is the formula you need to use:

```
if {ER100_ACCT_ORDER.ER100_ORD_TOT} * 100 mod 100 = 0 then
 0
else if {ER100_ACCT_ORDER.ER100_ORD_TOT} * 100 mod 10 = 0 then
 1
else
 2
```

:)

Comment: so you're saying 2.5 mod 1 = 0? isn't the remainder .5?

Comment: in crystal modulus is defined as: `Divides x by y and returns a remainder that is a whole number`

Comment: I find a new reason to hate crystal every day. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic851.html

Comment: The `mod` operation usually is an integer operation, that's not restricted to crystal.  It does not mean remainder strictly.

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a formula field instead of using the built-in summary field:

```
sum({mytable.myfield})
```

Then you can use your conditional formatting:

```
If ({@formula} mod 1 = 0) Then
        0
Else If ({@formula} mod .1 = 0) Then
        1
Else
        2
```